# Testing : Objective-C + Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, unit-testing

I'm trying to test my Objective-C project with embedded Swift code.

Xcode gives me errors with Swift classes used in Objective-C classes **e.g :**

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly) City *city;
```

> Unknown type name 'City'

Only for testing. Both classes are included in my test target.

If I choose *Jump to definition* for `City` Xcode opens my `swift.h` generated header.

Comment: Did you add `#import "ProjectName-Swift.h"`  to your test file (in Objective-c) ? This file is auto-generated by XCode when you compile your app target.

Answer (score 0):

`#import` your "-Swift.h" file to your test class & add the .Swift class to both target.
Then build your application once then you can use this Swift class in your test class.

Comment: Yes I did it. I even imported it in my .pch